# jquery setting range for if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to make an if statment with a value range, for example, if larger then blank but smaller then blank then do this.  What I have so far only seems to work for the first two if statements and I think it's because the first is less then and the second is greater.  It seems like because the third is also greater than that they share a value range and the third if statement doesn't work.  Is that right?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var about = $("#about_container").outerHeight(true) - 50;
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scroll <= ($("#top_section").outerHeight(true) + $("#grid").outerHeight(true))  ) { 
      $(".nav_middle_text").removeClass("selected");
      $(".nav_middle_text").addClass("notselected");
      $("#work").removeClass("notselected");
      $("#work").addClass("selected");    

   } else if (scroll > ($("#top_section").outerHeight(true) + $("#grid").outerHeight(true) - about) ) { 
      $(".nav_middle_text").removeClass("selected");
      $(".nav_middle_text").addClass("notselected");
      $("#about_link").removeClass("notselected");
      $("#about_link").addClass("selected"); 

   } else if (scroll > ($("#top_section").outerHeight(true) + $("#grid").outerHeight(true) + about) ) { 
      $(".nav_middle_text").removeClass("selected");
      $(".nav_middle_text").addClass("notselected");
      $("#services").removeClass("notselected");
      $("#services").addClass("selected"); 

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second condition, if your scroll value is larger than the outer heights of the section and the view (minus) that about variable, so it will be Definitely larger than the summation of the three values.

Answer (score 0):

okay, this is setting the range for the if statement, now it works:

if(leftPosition >= lowerLimit, leftPosition <= upperLimit)